# Justify footnote text in two column footnotes [memoir]

Tags: luatex, footnotes, memoir, two-column

The documentclass `memoir` provides a default option for two columns footnotes with the setting `\twocolumnfootnotes`, however the text in the footnote per default are aligned left and not justified.

How do set the footnote text to be justified?

MWE

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}
\twocolumnfootnotes

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

text\footnote{\lipsum} text text

\end{document}
```

*(LuaLaTex sample output):*

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be useful

I added the two lines and a little extra code

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\@twocolfootfmt}[1]{%
  \@preamtwofmt
  {%
    \hspace*{-\footparindent}% <-- added
    \footfootmark%
    \strut {\foottextfont #1}\strut\par}\allowbreak}

\renewcommand{\@preamtwofmt}{%
  \hsize .45\hsize
  \parindent=\z@
  \tolerance=5000\relax
  \raggedright
  \parindent=\footparindent% <-- added
  \leavevmode}

\makeatother

\setlength\footmarkwidth{1em}
\setlength\footparindent{1.5em}
\footmarkstyle{\hbox to \footmarkwidth{\textsuperscript{#1}\hfil}}



\twocolumnfootnotes

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

text\footnote{\lipsum[1-2]}\footnote{\lipsum[3-5]} text text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `\raggedright` be commented out for justified text?

Comment: @PeterWilson I wasn't paying attention, plus it will probably look bad to have this justified. So I interpreted the question as wanting to get the paragraph indentation back.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. Bonus question: if I want to change the size (i.e. vertical white space) of the margin between the two columns, how do go about this, in the above MWE? I want to decree this margin compared to the default settings of ```\twocolumnfootnotes```

Comment: @imdk4242 I have given a bonus answer to your newly asked question.